# Different value counts on same column using LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a database like below

```
+------------+---------------------------------------+--------+
| sender     | subject                               | day    |
+------------+---------------------------------------+--------+
| Darshana   | Re: [Dev] [Platform] Build error      | Monday |
| Dushan A   | (MOLDOVADEVDEV-49) GREG Startup Error | Monday |
+------------+---------------------------------------+--------+
```

I want to get the result using the above table. It should check if the subject contains the given word then add one to the that word column for a given day.

```
|Day      | "Dev"      | "startup"|
+---------+------------+----------+
| Monday  | 1          | 2        |
| Friday  | 0          | 3        |
```

I was thought of using DECODE function but I couldn't get the expected result.

Comment: that's basically a pivot query, which are not supported by mysql. the workarounds get ugly VERY fast. You'd be better off doing the transformation in client-side code.

Comment: Is it not possible to do, by using decode ?

Comment: mysql has no decode function.

Comment: But MySQL has `case`, which can do what decode can do, only more readable. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select day, sum(subject like '%Dev%') as Dev,
       sum(subject like '%startup%') as startup
from table t
group by day;
```